# iptables - simulate packet loss for a specific ip address

Tags: networking, iptables, packet-loss

I've read about statistic module that can help simulate packet loss:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.1 -j DROP
```

But is it possible to do that not for all incoming connections, but for a specific IP address?

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the source IP address in the rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s <SOURCE_IP_ADDRESS> -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.1 -j DROP
```